# How remove weather from today view in os X notification center?

Tags: macos, notifications

In my notification center in os x, I have disabled the weather widget. But still, under 'today' there is weather information. The weather widget itself still shows as disabled though!

How to completely remove weather info from the notification center?

[image: weather still shows even when disabled]

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove weather from Today without removing Today. The Weather widget is a separate interactive Weather widget, not part of Today. If you don't want weather to show within Today, you need to remove the Today widget.

Comment: But that also removes any other info the 'today' view might display, such as upcoming events (in this case). Isn't it weird that the 'today' widget in itself also contains mini-widgets that you can't edit?

Comment: @Piet Yes, that's true. Today is intended to be a summary of the day and the information provided in the widget is available in other widgets e.g. Calendar.